# Indistinguishable encryptions in the presence of an eavesdropper equivalence

Tags: encryption, symmetric, security-definition

I'm trying to prove that **definition 5** and **definition 6** in [this document](http://iiis.tsinghua.edu.cn/teaching/cryptoclass/lecture4.pdf) are equivalent. This is what I've done at the moment: Asume that the scheme has Indistinguishable encryptions in the presence of an eavesdropper (definition 5), then:

$$\mbox{Prob}[\mbox{Priv}_{\mathcal{A},\Pi}^{\mbox{eav}}(n)=1]=\mbox{Prob}[\texttt{output}(\mbox{Priv}_{\mathcal{A},\Pi}^{\mbox{eav}}(n,0))=0]+\mbox{Prob}[\texttt{output}(\mbox{Priv}_{\mathcal{A},\Pi}^{\mbox{eav}}(n,1))=1]=(1/2-\mbox{Prob}[\texttt{output}(\mbox{Priv}_{\mathcal{A},\Pi}^{\mbox{eav}}(n,0))=1])+\mbox{Prob}[\texttt{output}(\mbox{Priv}_{\mathcal{A},\Pi}^{\mbox{eav}}(n,1))=1]\leq 1/2+negl(n)$$

And we get that:

$$\mbox{Prob}[\texttt{output}(\mbox{Priv}_{\mathcal{A},\Pi}^{\mbox{eav}}(n,1))=1]-\mbox{Prob}[\texttt{output}(\mbox{Priv}_{\mathcal{A},\Pi}^{\mbox{eav}}(n,0))=1]\leq negl(n)$$

Now I'm trying to prove that:

$$\mbox{Prob}[\texttt{output}(\mbox{Priv}_{\mathcal{A},\Pi}^{\mbox{eav}}(n,0))=1]-\mbox{Prob}[\texttt{output}(\mbox{Priv}_{\mathcal{A},\Pi}^{\mbox{eav}}(n,1))=1]\leq negl(n)$$

For finishing the inequality with the absolute value. Is there someone who can help me with this? Thanks!

PS: I can understand the last line in the definition 6 in the document I've given: *where the probability is taken over...*

Can someone explain me that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found an answer to my question, I'm going to post it because it can be useful to someone out there.

The point is that, if we assume that $\mbox{Prob}[\mbox{Priv}_{\mathcal{A},\Pi}^{\mbox{eav}}(n)=1]\leq 1/2+negl(n)$, then $\mbox{Prob}[\mbox{Priv}_{\mathcal{A},\Pi}^{\mbox{eav}}(n)=0]\leq 1/2+negl(n)$ too (if this were not to happen, then we could create an adversary that solves the experiment with a better probability than $1/2+negl(n)$).

This allows us to use the same argument I've used for proving the first inequality for getting the inequality with absolute value.